# Add Array of Images to a UIScrollView ObjectiveC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, drag-and-drop

I did weeks of searching and finally found an example on Github that suited my needs. It was a trash drag example. I have now edited the example to my needs.

I now have only one problem. in my Scrollview I have 5 images, but they are all the same.

I want to know how to make each thumbnail a different image so when i drag an image from the Scrollview to the Imageview at the top it changes to that image i dragged form the scrollview.

Basically I want different images in my scrollview not all the same like I have.

I'm almost there and I got stuck on this one last thing I need to complete my battle.

As always any assistance would be much appreciated , below are some sample images and a link to my sample project.

Thank you.

[MySampleProject](http://www.blakeloizides.co.za/project.zip)

[image] 
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I did:

One. Rewrite the `- initWithFrame:` method of the `GalleryButton` class like this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame imageName:(NSString *)imgName
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        isInScrollview  = YES;

        CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 64);
        images = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];

        // here's the change:
        // instead of a constant name, use the `imgName` parameter
        [images setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imgName]];
        [self addSubview:images];

        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        self.layer.borderWidth = 2;
        self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then, rewrite the `- addAttachment:` method of the `GalleryScrollView` class like this:

```
- (void) addAttachment:(AttachmentItem *)attachment withImageNamed:(NSString *)imgName
{
    // everything stays the same (!), except this line:
    GalleryButton *btnAttachment = [[GalleryButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(startX, startY, width, height)];
    // is to be extended to:
    GalleryButton *btnAttachment = [[GalleryButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(startX, startY, width, height) imageName:imgName];
    ...
}
```

Then, in `- [HegakaDragAndDropRecycleBinViewController viewDidLoad]`, specify the filenames of the images you want to use:

```
[self.gallery addAttachment:item withImageNamed:@"recyclebin"];
[self.gallery addAttachment:item withImageNamed:@"canadian-maple"];
[self.gallery addAttachment:item withImageNamed:@"light-cherry"];
[self.gallery addAttachment:item withImageNamed:@"mozambique-wenge"];
[self.gallery addAttachment:item withImageNamed:@"canadian-maple"];
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Why would I get an error on this line: GalleryButton *btnAttachment = [[GalleryButton alloc] init:CGRectMake(startX, startY, width, height) imageName:imgName]; in my GalleryScrollView.m  "instance method -init:imageNamed not found?

Comment: How would I declare this i my header file?

Comment: it works now but i'm getting a warning in HegakaDragAndDropRecycleBinViewController viewdidload add attachement withImageNamed not found. with my images [self.gallery addAttachment:item withImageNamed:@"recyclebin"];

Comment: ***(gotta change the method declaration as well... common sense please!)***

Comment: This also worked:) 
    AttachmentItem *item = [[AttachmentItem alloc] initWithData:1 data:nil];
    [self.gallery addAttachment:item];
    [item release];
    
    AttachmentItem *item2 = [[AttachmentItem alloc] initWithData:2 data:nil];
    [self.gallery addAttachment:item2];
    [item2 release];

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** *In the future, it would be helpful for you to provide snippets of code that you think are specifically relevant to the problem. Posting the entire project and a problem you're encountering comes off as a bit lazy. What have you tried? Of what you tried before asking here, what didn't work?*

In your `GalleryButton.m` class, the `initWithFrame:` method has the code:

```
CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 64);
images = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
[images setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"light-cherry.png"]];
[self addSubview:images];
```

The variable name `images` is confusing because it's actually a **single** UIImageView, but this is the location where the image of the button is being assigned.

Solutions would be to either:

1. Alter the `initWithFrame:` initializer to also accept a `UIImage` object that can be passed into the `UIImageView`
2. Add a new method to your `GalleryButton` called `setImage:(UIImage*)image` or similar that sets the `image` on your `UIImageView` object.

Honestly if it were me, I would do both, unless you don't want that image to be modified after the button has been created, in which case you should only implement Option 1.